Share an image to Instagram story - Expo
I try to upload an image coming from a supabase storage (jpg or png), to instagram story using expo. I can't really use react-native-expo because I don't want to eject my app.
Note
I am trying using iOS, not android. Also, instagram and instagram-stories are authorized in my infoPlist.
Currently, here is my code to do this :
const handleShare = async () => {
    const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL('instagram-stories://app');

    const response = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    const mimetype = blob.type;
    const base64data = await convertBlobToBase64(blob);

    console.log(mimetype);
    
    const clipboardData = {
      'com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundImage': `data:${mimetype};base64,${base64data}`,
    };

    const data = JSON.stringify(clipboardData);
    await Clipboard.setStringAsync(data);

    const urlScheme = `instagram-stories://share?source_application=${MY_APP_ID}`;
    
    await Linking.openURL(urlScheme);
  };

The code to convert blob to base64 :
const convertBlobToBase64 = async (blob: Blob) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      // @ts-ignore
      resolve(reader.result!.split(',')[1]);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
};

The process work almost perfectly, it open instagram and the story, but my image is black..
I check many things, like the base64, no error on it, the mimetype is also correct, and right now I am stuck on what is wrong with it !
Any help is more than welcome !
I tried to use react-native-share, but I don't want to eject my expo app. Also I try with a perfect instagram sized / mimetyped image, still a black image, I try to decode the base64 to check if something was wrong but the base64 was ok
